# How does LayoutInflater deals with IDs when there are multiple copies of an .xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater

To make my point easier to explain, I will use an example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/thisIdIsVeryCool"/>
```

this is the .xml that I want to inflate and I will call it sublayout.xml

Now imagine that I inflate sublayout.xml in the main_layout.xml three times.

It does not give any error so I run the app on my device.
Now, right in front of my eyes, there are 3 EditText, all of wich with `thisIdIsVeryCool` as id.
this makes no sense to me...

What if i want to check if `thisIdIsVeryCool` is empty or not, and 2 of these EditText are indeed empty, but one of them is not?

Ok, it seems like i haven't ever tried to actually write a code like that and i'm lazy, but trust me, i've tried.
Actually, i've tryed a slightly different thing, and it seems that, when in the .java I refer to `thisIdIsVeryCool`, it affects only the inflated sublayout.xml that was created first.

so... how are called the others EditText?

And in general:

How does LayoutInflater deals with IDs?

Answer (score 0):

> Actually, i've tryed a slightly different thing, and it seems that, when in the .java I refer to thisIdIsVeryCool, it affects only the inflated sublayout.xml that was created first.

I am not sure that the described behavior is reliable. I would not make any assumptions about which widget you get for that ID, if there are multiple possibilities, given where and how you call `findViewById()`.

> how are called the others EditText?

Sometimes, you hold onto them when you inflate them.

Alternatively, depending on what you inflate them into, you might be able to distinguish between them by their parent.

When you call `findViewById()` to retrieve a widget, it is **your** job to ensure that you will get a unique result, by a combination of what `View` you call `findViewById()` on and what ID you supply as a parameter.

> How does LayoutInflater deals with IDs?

It assigns the `android:id` values to the widgets it creates, as you have them defined in the layout resources. Otherwise, it ignores them.

> this makes no sense to me...

Widget IDs are not guaranteed to be unique. In fact, frequently they are not unique, such as with rows in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

This is not significantly different than how the `id` attribute works in HTML. It's not like an HTML page is somehow invalid, and browsers will refuse to render it, just because you have two tags with the same `id`. Now, if because you have multiple tags with the same `id`, you encounter problems when trying to manipulate the DOM in JavaScript, that's your fault, not the browser's, not Sir Tim Berners-Lee's, or anyone else's. The same thing holds in Android: `android:id` attributes are there as a means of helping you find widgets. It is up to you to use layout resources, widget IDs, and `findViewById()` using patterns that work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, i thought having the same id for different things was not not possible, when in fact, it's totally ok. But if I **really** need these editText to have the same parent, how can i distinguish between them? Do i have to programmatically change the id for each of them?

Comment: @Leo300: "how can i distinguish between them?" -- it's unclear to me why you are inflating three tiny layout files for individual widgets. If you need them to have the same parent, have one layout file, with three widgets, each with an distinct ID. If your concern is repeating the formatting rules, extract those to a style resource and apply that to the widgets. If somebody is holding a gun to your head, and forcing you to use the same widget IDs for all three, you'll need to iterate over all children of the parent to find the Nth `EditText` with your desired ID, I guess.

Comment: ok, i should have been clear from the start. i'm creating a list of EditText (each `EditText` represent one item in this list) and what i'm trying to do is to let the user create one of these `EditText` by pressing a button. They should be able, however, to create a new EditText only if the previous one has been filled. so what i've tried to do is check if `thisIdIsVeryCool` is empty but, as i said before, when i refer to `thisIdIsVeryCool` it thinks only about the first one. This way you are able to create as many EditText as you want even if you have filled only the first one.

Comment: @Leo300: When you inflate the `EditText` widgets, hold onto them in an `ArrayList<EditText>`. Or, as I wrote earlier, you'll need to iterate over all children of the parent to find the Nth `EditText` with your desired ID.

Comment: In my case if `thisIdIsVeryCool` refferred to everyone of the `EditText` it would be better. but it does not. hence my original question about dealing with IDs. I cannot even set the ID programmatically since i can't know if the last one will be `4` or `36`

Comment: Thanks again sir. I will look into making an `ArrayList` since i saw that you can get the last value of the Array